# TikZ crosses-decoration does not work

Tags: tikz-pgf, decorations, pgf-decorations

When trying to compile the examples from the manual like

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\begin{document}
\tikz \fill [decorate,decoration={crosses}] [fill=blue!20,draw=blue,thick] (0,0) -- (2,1) arc (90:-90:.5) -- cycle;
\end{document}
```

all I receive is

```
! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/pgf/decoration/\pgfkeyscurrent
name ' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.
```

Is my tikz installation missing something or what do I do to make this work? The library is there (else I suppose the would be an error) and `zigzag` for instance is working.

Comment: works here with `\usetikzlibrary{decorations.shapes}` and `cycle;`

Comment: @dcmst Yeah, the semicolon was missing above. But adding the `shapes` sublibrary does the trick. I wonder why is this not documented. You might want to make this an answer, so I can accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The compilable snippet is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.shapes}
\begin{document}
\tikz \fill [decorate,decoration={crosses}] [fill=blue!20,draw=blue,thick] (0,0) -- (2,1) arc (90:-90:.5) -- cycle;
\end{document}
```

The `decorations.shapes` dependency is not directly documented in the example, but if you look carefully you'll notice that the `crosses` decoration is the first decoration introduced in the "TikZ Library `decorations.shapes`" section (Section 48.5.3, pag. 598) ;)